# webpack chrome extension chunk loading in content_script context

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webpack, content-script

I'm developing chrome extension in amd way. As js bundler I'm using webpack. I have extracted several entries, webpack constructed several chunks for them. My goal is to achieve chunk loading in context of content_script. By default behavior **webpack_require**.**ensure** function will create a new script tag with proper src and inject it into the dom:

```
__webpack_require__.e = function requireEnsure(chunkId, callback) {
/******/        // "0" is the signal for "already loaded"
/******/        if(installedChunks[chunkId] === 0)
/******/            return callback.call(null, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // an array means "currently loading".
/******/        if(installedChunks[chunkId] !== undefined) {
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId].push(callback);
/******/        } else {
/******/            // start chunk loading
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId] = [callback];
/******/            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
/******/            var script = document.createElement('script');
/******/            script.type = 'text/javascript';
/******/            script.charset = 'utf-8';
/******/            script.async = true;
/******/
/******/            script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + ({}[chunkId]||chunkId) + ".chunk.js";
/******/            head.appendChild(script); // INJECT INTO DOM
/******/        }
/******/    };
```

For my case I would like to load chunk  as separate request (like it works now) but execute in context of current content_script code: **eval** function.

To get smth like that:

```
/******/    __webpack_require__.e = function requireEnsure(chunkId, callback) {
/******/        // "0" is the signal for "already loaded"
/******/        if(installedChunks[chunkId] === 0)
/******/            return callback.call(null, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // an array means "currently loading".
/******/        if(installedChunks[chunkId] !== undefined) {
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId].push(callback);
/******/        } else {
/******/            // start chunk loading
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId] = [callback];
/******/            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
/******/            var src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + ({}[chunkId]||chunkId) + ".chunk.js";
/******/            var url = chrome.extension.getURL(src);
/******/            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
/******/            evalResponseText = function (xhr) {
/******/                eval(xhr.responseText + '//# sourceURL=' + url); // execute chunk's code in context of content_script
/******/                // context.completeLoad(moduleName);
/******/            };
/******/            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
/******/            xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
/******/                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
/******/                    evalResponseText.call(window, xhr);
/******/                }
/******/            };
/******/            xhr.send(null); // get chunk
/******/            
/******/        }
```

I already solved it by custom plugin injection into compilation process. The question if it's possible to achieve in 'legal' (simpler) way? Or not to use custom plugin and it could be solved by custom loader?

Thx a lot for any ideas.

Answer (score 4):

A legal way for chrome extension to inject a new content script is to do it in the background page via [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). Injected content scripts share the execution environment of your other content scripts, the so-called [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).

- content script:

  ```
  function loadScript(fileName, callback) {
      // fileName: file name relative to the extension root folder: 'js/blah.js'
      // callback: receives an array,
      //           in our case there'll be only one element as we inject in one frame, 
      //           each element is an injected script's last evaluated expression 
      //           that underwent internal JSON.stringify + JSON.parse 
      //           thus losing anything except simple stringifiable data
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
          action: 'loadContentScript',
          fileName: fileName,
      }, callback);
  }
  ```

  Usage:

  ```
  loadScript('js/lib/something.js', function(r) {
      console.log('something was dropped:', r);
      // call something in something
      .............
  }
  ```
- background script:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage(function(msg, sender, sendResponse)) {
      if (msg.action == 'loadContentScript') {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id, {
              file: msg.fileName,
              frameId: sender.frameId,
              runAt: 'document_start', // just in case, force an immediate execution
          }, sendResponse);
      }
      return true; // keeps the message channel open while async executeScript runs
  });
  ```
- manifest.json:

  Allow chrome.tabs.executeScript to inject into `https://example.com/` (or use `<all_urls>`):

  ```
  "permissions": ["tabs", "https://example.com/*"],
  ```

  Alternatively, and preferably, in case your extension is activated by an approved user gesture:

  ```
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  ```

  List of [user gestures](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab):

  - Executing a browser action i.e. toolbar icon click
  - Executing a page action i.e. toolbar icon click in modern Chrome
  - Executing a context menu item of your extension
  - Executing a keyboard shortcut of your extension from the commands API
  - Accepting a suggestion by your extension from the omnibox API

Comment: Thx for reply! Actually the initial question was refered to webpack and what the best way to modify/change chunk loading code generation mechanism =) But your answer give me an answer how to avoid eval() calling in my code and that's great too!

I already tried your suggestion with **chrome.executeScript** but got some confusing error messages. What I'm trying to do is to use override requirejs.load global function to call sendMessage and executeScript on background page. Chrome is able to find module but cannot execute for some reason.

Comment: Well, webpack can't circumvent the inherent restrictions of chrome extensions, so any extension-specific script loading functionality it could ever provide would be basically along these lines. Maybe in the bright future when Chrome implements ES6-modules for extensions.

Comment: If you're trying to execute the response object, it's just a leftover of whatever was last evaluated castrated by internal stringification (see the comments in my code). So just access the new module directly (it should register itself in a global `modules` or `exports` object, for example).

Comment: Not sure if I have clear understanding your words about stringify... I'm trying to load content script which amd module by executeScript as you described above.

Comment: So the idea is pretty straight forward: I have requirejs in chrome extension as content script. All I want is to be able load any requested amd module (by require(['./my/file.js'] i.e.) as content script as well.

executeSxript fits pretty well but requirejs unable to process response module.. Have no idea why for now..

Comment: I mean the response object is not a module. Forget it. I should have never mentioned it. Just rework your modules to self-register in a global object like `exports`.

Comment: Another/better method is to automatically intercept script injection and evaluate in the content script context: [scriptTagContext](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/scriptTagContext) wrapper.

Comment: that fileName needs to be relative to the root folder (and not relative to the folder where the scripts are placed) is a very important piece of information and saved me more headache at https://github.com/qownnotes/web-companion, thank you!