# How to dynamically append the content script in browser extension.?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to append the script on content script from the API response.

Following is the content.js

```
    locationHref = window.location.href;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: locationHref,
        value: false
    }, function (data) {
        localStorage();
        console.log('contetn js ', data);
    });

    function localStorage() {
        chrome.storage.local.get('script', (items) => {
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.innerHTML = items.script;
            document.body.appendChild(s);
            if (items.responseData) {
                setTimeout((r) => {

                    loadPopUp(items.responseData); // this method is not triggering

                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }
```

And following is the  background.js file

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
        fetchData(msg.action, sendResponse);
        return true;
    });


    function fetchData(url, sendResponse) {
        fetch("myscript.js", {
                method: 'GET',
            }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(response => {
                chrome.storage.local.set({
                    "script": response
                }, function () {});
                sendResponse(response);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }
```

And myscript.js has the following code.

```
function loadPopUp(data) {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<h4 style="color:white; font-size: 25px; text-align: center; margin-top: 15px;">
        ${data.name} has <span style="font-weight:bold">${data.count}</span> gene count</h4>`)
}
```

API response has the loadPopUp() method, after creating the script tag I am trying to call the loadPopup method but it is giving `undefined` error.

How can I solve this problem.?

Comment: DOM `script` runs in page context, not in the "isolated world" of content scripts. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879926/).

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying? There is a bg script, a content and a myScript. Content and bg are successfully running.You send a message from your content to your bg and as a callback run a function in your content script. Your bg runs and fetches myScript the and you send it as a JSON to your content script. This should be the data you are able to see in console.log("contetn js"); You also run a function now called localStorage(). Am i correct in my understanding? All this you are doing, because you want to execute a 2nd script based after both bg and content are loaded.

Comment: Also, please log data before calling localStorage(). loadPopup() will be undefined because it is not defined anywhere in the script. Check what is logging when you log data, and it might give you a better idea as to how you can call this function.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success in embedded environments (i.e., where I do not have access to the main page code) loading the scripts directly into the head.

Here is what I do.

```js
const exampleScript = {
   name: "p5.js",
   src: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js",
   id: "p5-script"
};

const loadScript = (scriptToLoad, callback) => {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = scriptToLoad.src;
    script.id = scriptToLoad.id;
    script.onload = () => { 
        callback();
    }
    script.onerror = (e) => console.error("error loading" +  scriptToLoad.name + "script", e);
    document.head.append(script);
}

loadScript(exampleScript, () => {
   //...whatever you do after loading the script
});
```

The issue you are likely having is that you load it into the body instead of into the head.

Here is an article that explains it. https://aaronsmith.online/easily-load-an-external-script-using-javascript/